# How to stop a loop in Groovy

Tags: arrays, list, loops, collections, groovy

From the collection `fileMatches`, I want to assign the maps with the 10 greatest values to a new collection called `topTen`.  So I try to make a collection:

```
def fileMatches = [:].withDefault{[]}
new File('C:\\BRUCE\\ForensicAll.txt').eachLine { line ->
def (source, matches) = line.split (/\t/)[0, 2]
fileMatches[source] << (matches as int)
```

I want to iterate through my collection and grab the 10 maps with greatest values.  One issue I might be having is that the output of this doesn't look quite like I imagined.  One entry for example:

```
C:\cygwin\home\pro-services\git\projectdb\project\stats\top.h:[984, 984]
```

The advice so far has been excellent, but I'm not sure if my collection is arranged to take advantage of the suggested solutions (I have `filename:[984, 984]` when maybe I want `[filename, 984]` as the map entries in my collection).  I don't understand this stuff quite yet (like how `fileMatches[source] << (matches as int)` works, as it produces the line I posted immediately above (with `source:[matches, matches]` being the output).

Please advise, and thanks for the help!

Comment: So to get this straight: `fileMatches` is a list of maps, each map of the form `[someFilename: value]`? And you want to retrieve the 10 entries in `fileMatches` with the greatest values for `someFilename`?

Comment: well I'm not actually sure (newbie here).  Using this code: `def fileMatches = [:].withDefault{[]}
new File('C:\\documents\\ForensicAll.txt').eachLine { line ->
    
    def (source, matches) = line.split (/\t/)[0, 2]
    fileMatches[source] << (matches as int)` I end up with a bunch of things that look like this, which might not be what I want  `C:\programs\xwing\lasers.h:[25, 25]`

Comment: Sorry, but should clear up your question as well as your code example. We're confused. Show us the given inputs and the expected outputs.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I tried to clear it up :)

Comment: I made a new post addressing the definition of my collection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408556/clearing-up-confusion-with-maps-collections-groovy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this another approach, using some `Collection`'s skills. It does what you want with some simplicity...

```
def fileMatches = [um: 123, dois: 234, tres: 293, quatro: 920, cinco: 290];
def topThree;

topThree = fileMatches.sort({tup1, tup2 -> tup2.value <=> tup1.value}).take(3);
```

Result:

```
Result: [quatro:920, tres:293, cinco:290]
```

Comment: You could change your compareTo to: tup2.value <=> tup1.value

Comment: Good addition! I didn't knew this comparator :)

Comment: I ended up not completely understanding your question, but it's good that it's solved!

Comment: How would I change this to grab the smallest 10 values?

Comment: Something like `topTen = fileMatches.sort({tup1, tup2 -> tup1.value <=> tup2.value}).take(10)`

Answer (score 2):

You might find it easier to use some of the built-in collection methods that Groovy provides, e.g.:

```
fileMatches.sort { a, b -> b.someFilename <=> a.someFilename }[0..9]
```

or

```
fileMatches.sort { it.someFileName }[-1..-10]
```

The range on the end there will cause an error if you have < 10 entries, so it may need some adjusting if that's your case.

Comment: You can simplify the sort to just `fileMatches.sort { it.someFilename }`.  The single arg closure will be applied to both sides, and the results compared.

Comment: @ataylor - Although that won't descending-sort them; it could still probably be used with a negative range to get the last 10, or something.