# Clearing up confusion with Maps/Collections (Groovy)

Tags: arrays, list, collections, groovy, maps

I define a collection that is supposed to map two parts of a line in a tab-separated text file:

```
def fileMatches = [:].withDefault{[]}

new File('C:\\BRUCE\\ForensicAll.txt').eachLine { line ->
def (source, matches) = line.split (/\t/)[0, 2]
fileMatches[source] << (matches as int)}
```

I end up with entries such as `filename:[984, 984]` and I want `[filename : 984]` . I don't understand how `fileMatches[source] << (matches as int)` works.  How might I get the kind of collection I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you are trying to do. How, for example, would you handle a line where the two values are different instead of the same (which seems to be what is implied by your code)? A map requires unique keys, so you can't use `filename` as a key if it has multiple values.

That said, you could get the result you want with the data implied by your result using:

```
def fileMatches = [:]
new File('C:\\BRUCE\ForensicAll.txt').eachLine { line ->
    def (source, matches) = line.split(/\t/)[0,2]
    fileMatches[source] = (matches as int)
}
```

But this will clobber the data (i.e., you will always end up with the second value from the last line your file. If that's not what you want you may want to rethink your data structure here.

Alternatively, assuming you want unique values, you could do:

```
def fileMatches = [:].withDefault([] as Set)
new File('C:\\BRUCE\ForensicAll.txt').eachLine { line ->
    def (source, matches) = line.split(/\t/)[0,2]
    fileMatches[source] << (matches[1] as int)
}
```

This will result in something like `[filename:[984]]` for the example data and, e.g., `[filename:[984, 987]]` for files having those two values in the two columns you are checking.

Again, it really depends on what you are trying to capture. If you could provide more detail on what you are trying to accomplish, your question may become answerable...

Comment: Thank you.  I've got many lines of text that look like this:  `C:\cygwin\home\pro-services\git\projectdb\project\counter.cpp 15 421` (Note: those are tab separated).  Each line in the file has a unique path like `C:\cygwin\...` (which I perhaps confusingly symbolized as `filename` in my question) and unique numbers, and I want to map each unique path to the second number on it's line using `line.split(/\t/)[0,2]` to get entries in a (collection?) that look like this: `C:\cygwin\etc. : 421` .   The big goal is to later isolate the paths with the 10 largest values mapped to them.

Comment: @blaughli: I think, then, that the first example, which I just updated, should meet your case...

Comment: Trying to append `(matches[1] as int)` to `fileMatches` without giving it a default setting throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: I used `fileMatches << ["$source" : matches as int]` and got exactly what I needed.  Thanks for the help))